# Why Does ETS Say My Data Has No Seasonality?

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

Why is `ets` telling me there is no seasonality to my data?

```
> hwin <- ets(train.ts, model = "MAA")
Error in ets(train.ts, model = "MAA") : Nonseasonal data
```

Is there not a clear, daily seasonality to this data? Please note that the image below is of my full dataset, where as the sample code below only contains a partial dataset.

[image]

I know there isn't much trend, but seasonality should be there, right?

This is my code:

```
d <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17349, 17350, 17351, 17352, 
                                       17353, 17354, 17355, 17356, 17357, 17358, 17359, 17360, 17361, 
                                       17362, 17363, 17364, 17365, 17366, 17367, 17368, 17369, 17370, 
                                       17371, 17372, 17373, 17374, 17375, 17376, 17377, 17378, 17379, 
                                       17380, 17381, 17382, 17383), class = "Date"), Ratio = c(67, 50, 
                                                                                               67, 50, 100, 50, 33, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 75, 0, 0, 75, 100, 
                                                                                               67, 33, 33, 33, 50, 50, 67, 100, 67, 50, 25, 25, 33, 33, 100, 
                                                                                               33, 0)), .Names = c("Date", "Ratio"), row.names = 183:217, class = "data.frame")

library(xts)
dates = as.Date(d$Date,"%Y-%m-%d")
ratios.ts = xts(d$Ratio,dates)

library("forecast")
library("zoo")

plot(ratios.ts)

nValid <- 6
nTrain <- length(ratios.ts) - nValid
train.ts <- window(ratios.ts, start = as.Date("2017-07-02"), end = as.Date("2017-07-02") + nTrain)
valid.ts <- window(ratios.ts, start = as.Date("2017-07-02") + nTrain + 1, end = as.Date("2017-07-02") + nTrain + nValid)

hwin <- ets(train.ts, model = "MAA")
hwin.pred <- forecast(hwin, h = nValid, level = 0)

plot(hwin.pred, ylim = c(-20,120), ylab = "Ratio", xlab = "Date", bty = "l", xaxt = "n", main = "", flty = 2)
lines(hwin.pred$fitted, lwd = 2, col = "blue")
```

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't tell `xts()` that the data were periodic. The `frequency` argument allows you to do this. You need to tell it how many observations correspond to the unit time interval. If you had monthly data this would be 1/12 say. Do read ?xts though for details of the specific requirements here; I may have the input incorrect for **xts** as I use these things too infrequently for it to stick and there are several of these time-series data objects that have similar but not unique interfaces and arguments. This is also off topic for [stats.se] as it is about a programming problem not a stats one.

Comment: Could you post your data?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks for that I'll try it out.  Funnily enough, I first posted this question on stackoverflow.com where someone said, "this isn't a programming question, it's a stats question."  Maybe there should be an intermediary site lol!

Comment: @GavinSimpson Upon changing my code to `ratios.ts = xts(d$Ratio,dates,frequency = 365.25)` addressing the frequency, I still get the same error.  Any ideas?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sorry, I can't post the full data set; however, the sample data should be sufficient as the error I am hoping to resolve occurs for both sets.  Thanks.

Comment: Try `ets(as.ts(train.ts), model = "MAA")`, assuming `train.ts` is a zoo object by the time you come to model it. `?ets` indicates that `x` is supposed to be a vector or `'ts'` classed object. It may be `ets()` doesn't know how to handle what you are passing it.

Comment: @GavinSimpson train.ts is not a zoo object; it's an `xts` object.  `ets(as.ts(train.ts), model = "MAA")` seems to result in the same error but I think you are on the right track thinking that ets doesn't understand what I am passing it which is probably due to the fact that my data is daily, not weekly, monthly or yearly.

Comment: @user1477388 If it weren't coercible to zoo object then why load **zoo**, and the `window` method wouldn't have worked. I was unsure if  the zoo method for `window` would preserve the xts- and zoo-ness of the underlying series or just return a zoo object. I'm also not sure you can specify a decimal for `frequency`, which may still be the cause of the problem...

Comment: @GavinSimpson I think I had `zoo` in there from a previous attempt; it should be disregarded.  Something interesting, though:  It seems like xts understands that the data is daily.  A quick call outputs that it determines the data to be daily.  So, why isn't ets getting the memo?  `> periodicity(ratios.ts)
Daily periodicity from 2017-01-01 to 2017-08-06 `

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple issues.

1. As [Gavin Simpson points out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300809/why-does-ets-say-my-data-has-no-seasonality#comment571754_300809), you don't tell R or `ets()` that your data have a seasonal cycle.

As a matter of fact, I'm not sure what seasonal cycle you believe to be obvious about your data: weekly (`frequency=7`), monthly (`frequency=30` or some such) or yearly (`frequency=365`)?

2. If we do specify a seasonal cycle, let's say weekly,

   ```
   hwin <- ets(ts(train.ts[,1],frequency=7), model = "MAA")
   ```

   then `ets()` quite understandably complains about specifying a *multiplicative* seasonality (the initial "M") for data that contains zeros. If you specify *additive* seasonality, `ets()` will fit it without errors:

   ```
   hwin <- ets(ts(train.ts[,1],frequency=7), model = "MAA")
   ```

   I'm a bit unsure whether this makes a lot of sense, though, because:
3. Just descriptively, at least weekly seasonality is far from apparent in your data:

   ```
   seasonplot(ts(train.ts[,1],frequency=7))
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, that sheds some light.  Let me clarify: The seasonality I was referring to was daily, not weekly.  Do you have any ideas how to specify daily frequency?  I have at least one years worth of data from `2016-08-11` to `2017-08-11`.  What would the `ts` configuration look like for something like that?

Comment: What's the seasonal *cycle*? Your data are daily. How many (daily) data points make one cycle? Is it 7 days (weekly seasonality), 14 (biweekly), ~30 (monthly) or 365 (yearly)? Any one, or even multiple ones, can make sense. Or do you actually have subdaily data that repeat day-over-day, e.g., hourly data with a cycle length of 24, or half-hourly data with a cycle length of 48? In that case, you'd need to also specify your subdaily timestamps.

Comment: I have 365 data points i.e. for each day in one year, a value is recorded between 0 and 100.  I have set the frequency to seven based on my reading from an article I found and I've asked another question as I now have gotten the ets function to return predictions (using ANA, not MAA) here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300869/how-can-i-get-more-accurate-predictions-with-extreme-values.  The data is not sub-daily.  It seems my predictions are off by 25 currently (MAE = 25).

Comment: If you have 365 data points, then you could potentially model weekly or monthly seasonality, but not yearly, since you haven't observed two full seasonal cycles. I'd suggest that you don't set your frequency based on some external article, but based on how often you expect seasonal cycles to recur. For instance, temperatures have yearly seasonality, not weekly or monthly. And supermarket sales have a strong weekly seasonality (higher sales on Friday and Saturday), which is far stronger than the yearly cycle (and the very weak monthly or biweekly paycheck cycle).

Comment: You may want to look at [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/), a free online forecasting textbook.

Comment: I have been reading Practical TimeSeries Forecasting with R (http://www.forecastingbook.com/) but I will definitely check out the exponential smoothing chapter of the book you provided (https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/1).  I am at the point where I am trying to apply the things I've learned but am struggling a bit to fit my exact needs.  I am only trying to predict the next 1-7 days based on the previous and I have 365 days of data to work with.