# How Can I Get More Accurate Predictions with Extreme Values?

Tags: r, time-series

I have 365 days of data ranging from 0 to 100.

Shown in **blue** are the predicted values. The **red** line shows the actual values over the validation period. The solid line predicts the training data while the dashed line predicts the testing data.

**How can I get more accurate predictions when my data has such extreme values?**

[image]

**My MAE is approx. 25** which is what I am hoping to improve:

```
> accuracy(hwin.pred, valid.ts)
                   ME     RMSE      MAE  MPE MAPE      MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
Training set 2.093110 32.90566 26.46510 -Inf  Inf 0.8101071 0.03867724        NA
Test set     2.473318 29.20464 23.04994 -Inf  Inf 0.7055677 0.01577363         0
```

My code uses 365 days of data (as stated above) so I didn't want to provide all of it here in the interest of brevity but I can do so if it would help.

The following is my actual code that produced the above plot (excepting the data):

```
library("forecast")

ratios.ts <- ts(d[,2], frequency = 7)

nValid <- 21
nTrain <- length(ratios.ts) - nValid
train.ts <- window(ratios.ts, start = c(1, 1), end = c(1, nTrain))
valid.ts <- window(ratios.ts, start = c(1, nTrain + 1), end = c(1, + nTrain + nValid))

hwin <- ets(train.ts, model = "ANA")
hwin.pred <- forecast(hwin, h = nValid, level = 0)

plot(hwin.pred, ylim = c(-20,120), ylab = "Ratio", xlab = "Date", bty = "l", xaxt = "n", main = "", flty = 2)
lines(hwin.pred$fitted, lwd = 2, col = "blue")
lines(valid.ts, col = "red")

accuracy(hwin.pred, valid.ts)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact model you're using, but most models predict a best estimate, and can also provide an uncertainty bound on that estimate. Your data likely has some unpredictable component (either noise, or other variance your model doesn't capture). If you plot confidence intervals on the predictions, you'll probably see that most of those extreme values are captured within them. If you want to get a better mean projection result, you'll need to use a better model (dependent on the data).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to incentivise AI to make risky predictions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633338/how-to-incentivise-ai-to-make-risky-predictions) Also see my answer to [Regression on imbalanced and zero-inflated data. How to deal with less frequent values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/627086/247274)