# Historical average with exponential smoothing model

Tags: r, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

This topic similar with this one
[R Time Series Analysis forecast result always remains same](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147279/r-time-series-analysis-forecast-result-always-remains-same)
But I perfrom exponential smoothing model in R.

```
df=structure(list(date = structure(1:12, .Label = c("01.01.2017", 
"01.02.2017", "01.03.2017", "01.04.2017", "01.05.2017", "01.06.2017", 
"01.07.2017", "01.08.2017", "01.09.2017", "01.10.2017", "01.11.2017", 
"01.12.2017"), class = "factor"), value = c(200L, 100L, 460L, 
300L, 280L, 280L, 140L, 180L, 80L, 80L, 180L, 60L), common = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "158150- 01195т", class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", 
"value", "common"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
```

i perform forecast for each groups separately) using ets function from forecast package (common is grouping variable)

here forecast for initial dataset
[image]

it is wrong result, but the main is that forecast on 1 year age ahead has static values(like historical mean)
[image]

How can i understand why forecast show same value in exponential smoothing model. Is it possible to fix it?

I can provide my R code, if it is needed.

Comment: `ets()` probably selects a non-seasonal and non-trended model, which yields flat line forecasts. [Here are a few similar questions and answers (from me).](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1352+flat)

Comment: @StephanKolassa, i will check i and write you.

Comment: @StephanKolassa,can forecast package set seasonal model using ets()? i can see where do it in argument.

Comment: You can force `ets()` to use an additive seasonal model with the parameter `model="ZZA"`, or a multiplicative one using `model="ZZM"`. Unfortunately, there is no way to specify *either* one. However, if `ets()` chooses a non-seasonal model, it will likely have good reasons for it. I would be skeptical about being able to improve on its model selection. Do seasonal models truly improve out-of-sample forecast accuracy?

Comment: Incidentally, does your time series structure have the correct frequency attribute? If not, then `ets()` will not do anything seasonal. [Why Does ETS Say My Data Has No Seasonality?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/300809/1352)